# Problems with CPLEX in Eclipse for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, libraries, cplex

I am trying to setup properly Cplex for using it in Eclipse by following the instructions
found on this website: http://www4.ncsu.edu/~yzhang13/eclipse-cplex-linux2.html 
When I finish all the steps I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible  
/home/used/concert/lib/x86_sles10_4.1/static_pic/libconcert.a when searching for -lconcert
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lconcert
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible    
/home/used/cplex/lib/x86_sles10_4.1/static_pic/libilocplex.a when searching for -lilocplex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lilocplex
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible 
/home/used/cplex/lib/x86_sles10_4.1/static_pic/libcplex.a when searching for -lcplex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcplex
```

Doen anybody know what may be causing this? 
(Note that I checked my cplex make file in order to have the libraries in the proper order based on the syntax of the make file).
Just to make things more clear my CPLEX make file for the libraries is the following:

```
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# Link options and libraries
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------

CPLEXBINDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/bin/$(BINDIST)
CPLEXJARDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/cplex.jar
CPLEXLIBDIR   = $(CPLEXDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)
CONCERTLIBDIR = $(CONCERTDIR)/lib/$(SYSTEM)/$(LIBFORMAT)

CCLNDIRS  = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR) -L$(CONCERTLIBDIR)
CLNDIRS   = -L$(CPLEXLIBDIR)
CCLNFLAGS = -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -m32 -lm -lpthread
CLNFLAGS  = -lcplex -m32 -lm -lpthread
JAVA      = java  -d32 -Djava.library.path=$(CPLEXDIR)/bin/x86_sles10_4.1 -classpath 
$(CPLEXJARDIR):
```

And the order I use when I add the libraries is (concert, ilocplex, cplex, m pthread).

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The problem was that I accidentally had a X32 version of CPLEX running on my X64 machine.